# shortcuts/links to windows partition disappear on reboot

Tags: 11.10

Ubuntu 11.10 recognizes my Windows 7 partition OK. Since that is where my work has historically been, I created links to various files and folders there. Everythingś fine until I reboot. Then the icon reverts to the generic and I am informed the link is no longer valid. I created the links by right-clicking the folder or file and selecting "Make Link" in the Windows folder, then dragging it to the Ubuntu desktop. How can I fix this? BTW, it worked OK with Kubuntu; I got seduced by the sexy Unity desktop.....

Answer (score 2):

Windows partitions (ntfs) are not mounted when you reboot ubuntu. So your link is invalid.

To do automount :

**Option 1**

Use NTFS Configuration Tool

You can install it from Ubuntu Software Center.

**Option 2**

Manually edit `/etc/fstab`.

Follow [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=872197)

Answer (score 0):

Follow this guide - To mount partition automatically after reboot - This should fix your issue.

http://www.webupd8.org/2011/11/how-to-mount-partitions-automatically.html